# Cannot switch to win32 application using WhiteLibrary and handle it

Tags: windows, automation, robotframework

I need help in a win32 application automation, using robotframework WhiteLibrary.

After "signing in" in one window... another windows open and I can't reach the new 
window.
How can I change the focus and handle the new window to interact with it?

I inspect it using inspect.exe and I have this information:
ControlType:    UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType:    "dialog"

Ex:

```
    Library          WhiteLibrary

**Login in: Dialog window**
Launch Application          ${TEST APPLICATION}
Attach Window               title
sleep  3
Click Item                  id:1000
Input Text To Textbox       id:1000   user
Click Item                  id:1001
Input Text To Textbox       id:1001   password
click button                text:OK
sleep  3

**After OK open second Dialog Window back to the first Dialog Window:** 

Attach Application By Name  title2
**fail: WhiteException: Could not find process named: title2
at TestStack.White.Application.Attach(String executable)**
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] to share with us regarding your problem?

Comment: Ex:

Library     WhiteLibrary

Login in: Dialog window

Launch Application     ${TEST APPLICATION}

Attach Window          title
sleep 3
Click Item    id:1000
Input Text To Textbox     id:1000     user
Click Item     id:1001
Input Text To Textbox     id:1001     password
click button     text:OK
sleep 3

After OK open second Dialog Window back to the first Dialog Window: 

Attach Application By Name     title2
fail: WhiteException: Could not find process named: title2 at TestStack.White.Application.Attach(String executable)

Comment: Through the [edit] functionality you can update your question. This is preferred over the comment section as it should be used to ask for clarifications. Either to the person who created the question, or for this person to ask for clarifications on a comment. Would you be able to provide an example with say notepad, or another generically available application?

Answer (score 0):

Correct steps:

1. Launch Application `${TEST APPLICATION}`
2. Attach Application By Id `${pid}`
3. Attach Window `title`